# Jquery event functions are only called in Chrome

Tags: jquery, function, events

I shortened it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dauerselect').click(function() {
    alert('hello');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="dauerselect">
  <option value='' disabled selected>▼ Bitte wählen</option>
  <option value="pay45">Eine Schulstunde (45 Minuten)</option>
  <option value="pay60">Eine Zeitstunde (60 Minuten)</option>
  <option value="pay90">Zwei Schulstunden (90 Minuten)</option>
  <option value="pay120">Zwei Zeitstunden (120 Minuten)</option>
  <option value="pay180">Vier Schulstunden (180 Minuten)</option>
</select>
```

'hello' is only shown in Chrome. Not in Firefox and not in IE. It seems to be an error Chrome tolerates but other browsers not. Please help me.

Comment: Please include your html code and the code for the function `makeEdit`

Comment: What does that error says, since you think that there is one?

Comment: It's an assumption. The code works in Chrome, but not in other browsers.

Comment: It works for me in firefox

Comment: Oh. My code comes from different files and is included via php include_once into the main page. Is it maybe a problem?

Comment: The more code you provide us with, the better chance we have for helping you.

Comment: It works for me in Safari, too.

Comment: Are you sure you want this to be a `click` event, not `change`? So your handler will be called even if they don't change the menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problems were the keywords async and await in jquery code. Without these words it works in Firefox now, but not yet in IE11...

This jquery line was the problem in IE:

```
return new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Removed and works.

Seems that Chrome is really the best browser from this point of view. Thank you all for your effort. You made the beginning for solving my problem.

For all visitors: Remember, you mustn't use the keywords async and await and the code line at all in your jquery code to make it work outside Chrome!!

By the way, this is the matter in question: https://nachhilfe-hannover.org